# Heroku: DNS & SSL - certificate not working. What are the correct DNS / SSL settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns, zerigo

I have a [heroku app](http://gwvz.herokuapp.com) that should be reachable via http://www.gewerbeverzeichnis-rj.ch

http://www.gewerbeverzeichnis-rj.ch should always be forwarded to the www subdomain.

I have a GeoTrust QuickSSL-Cert for http://www.gewerbeverzeichnis-rj.ch already on heroku.

These are my cert settings:

```
     $ heroku certs:info
Fetching SSL Endpoint toyama-4181.herokussl.com info for gwvz... done
Certificate details:
Common Name(s): gewerbeverzeichnis-rj.ch
                www.gewerbeverzeichnis-rj.ch

Expires At:     2015-01-30 12:33 UTC
Issuer:         /serialNumber=RnbwGOxjP0RwwLrQg3bvLgnO151VL0E9/OU=GT63736657/OU=See www.geotrust.com/resources/cps (c)14/OU=Domain     Control Validated - QuickSSL(R) Premium/CN=www.gewerbeverzeichnis-rj.ch
Starts At:      2014-01-28 07:26 UTC
Subject:        /serialNumber=RnbwGOxjP0RwwLrQg3bvLgnO151VL0E9/OU=GT63736657/OU=See www.geotrust.com/resources/cps (c)14/OU=Domain     Control Validated - QuickSSL(R) Premium/CN=www.gewerbeverzeichnis-rj.ch
SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.
```

And here are my DNS settings on Zerigo DNS:

[Screenshot on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qhglarclfffz4j1/Screenshot%202014-01-29%2009.26.59.png)

2 questions:

- Why is my root domain not forwarded to the www subdomain?
- Why is the certificate test on https://ssltools.geotrust.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp failing?

Any help much appreciated, been stuck here for a while!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CNAME entry should be to the SSL endpoint *NOT* to your Heroku application.

```
www.gewerbeverzeichnis-rj.ch  CNAME  toyama-4181.herokussl.com
```

That will stop the SSL error message rather than trying to use the wildcard *.herokuapp.com certificate that it is using when you CNAME to .herokuapp.com

This particular setup step is at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#dns-and-domain-configuration

Answer (score -1):

The site seems to be loading a certificate issued by digicert to *.herokuapp.com which means that your heroku app is not correctly configured to use the certificate you have uploaded.

Comment: I agree that it most be ill-configured but I don't know where I could have gone wrong. I followed this guide step by step:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Any idea how to debug?

Comment: Did you modify your DNS settings and create an ALIAS or ANAME record to the endpoint as mentioned in the url?

Comment: these are the records i have created: [screenshot1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ec1e7l7lv25zib/Screenshot%202014-01-29%2014.25.09.png) and: [screenshot 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t8e6owb1vipnn8w/Screenshot%202014-01-29%2014.25.32.png). which alias or aname should there be?